# How to create a chart in a cell of the Bootstrap-vue tables?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, bootstrap-vue

I'm trying to use Bootstrap-vue tables. I'm trying to add a column "chart" where I can show the data in a chart. Something like:

[image]

I'm interested in the "graph" type chart (not shown in the image). Is it something that can be done with the Bootstrap-vue tables?

Answer (score 0):

slot:cell
Here is the code from bootstrap-vue.org:
Inside the template you can put your chart element. And use the 'data' to get the information that you want. Like data.item is the entire that for that row

```
<template>
  <div>
    <b-table small :fields="fields" :items="items" responsive="sm">
      <!-- A virtual column -->
      <template v-slot:cell(index)="data">
        {{ data.index + 1 }}
      </template>

      <!-- A custom formatted column -->
      <template v-slot:cell(name)="data">
        <b class="text-info">{{ data.value.last.toUpperCase() }}</b>, <b>{{ data.value.first }}</b>
      </template>

      <!-- A virtual composite column -->
      <template v-slot:cell(nameage)="data">
        {{ data.item.name.first }} is {{ data.item.age }} years old
      </template>

      <!-- Optional default data cell scoped slot -->
      <template v-slot:cell()="data">
        <i>{{ data.value }}</i>
      </template>
    </b-table>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    data() {
      return {
        fields: [
          // A virtual column that doesn't exist in items
          'index',
          // A column that needs custom formatting
          { key: 'name', label: 'Full Name' },
          // A regular column
          'age',
          // A regular column
          'sex',
          // A virtual column made up from two fields
          { key: 'nameage', label: 'First name and age' }
        ],
        items: [
          { name: { first: 'John', last: 'Doe' }, sex: 'Male', age: 42 },
          { name: { first: 'Jane', last: 'Doe' }, sex: 'Female', age: 36 },
          { name: { first: 'Rubin', last: 'Kincade' }, sex: 'Male', age: 73 },
          { name: { first: 'Shirley', last: 'Partridge' }, sex: 'Female', age: 62 }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

Here is the documentation
https://bootstrap-vue.org/docs/components/table#tables
Go to Custom data rendering

Comment: Hi! thank you for your reply but the example does not create a graph in a cell. I read the docs but could not find an example that shows how to do it.